# Different return type due to available or not query parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have "pattern" issue that I'm not able to solve when making an API with .NET CORE 3.1.

I have a `CustomerController` and I need to return all customers if no query parameters are passed with a return type `IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>`.
If one query parameter (`customerName`) is passed I need to return only one customer (the first I found with my logic).

This implementation cause a runtime problem because the app is not able to redirect to the correct controller:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

MyApi.Controllers.CustomersController.GetCustomerTours (MyApi)
MyApi.Controllers.CustomersController.GetCustomerTours (MyApi)
```

These are the methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>>> GetCustomerTours()
```

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDTO>> GetCustomerTours(string customerName)
```

and this what I want to obtain when call the API:

`../customers`

`../customers?customerName=myCustomerName`

How can I tell to my API that I need a specific method call depending on the presence of a query parameter or not?

Answer (score 0):

(1)

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CustomerDTO>>> GetCustomerTours()
```

for

```
../customers
```

(2)

```cs
[HttpGet("{customerName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDTO>> GetCustomerTours(string customerName)
```

for

```
../customers/myCustomerName
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths , for example

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried also the second point you write.Is it normal that there are no difference to call `../customers/myCustomerName` or `../customers?myCustomerName`